# Is it possible to hack a StackOverflow account?

Tags: account-security

Is it possible that a StackOverflow account can be hacked without the owner knowing?

If a StackOverflow account is hacked, is any other information (like social media passwords) exposed other than StackOverflow information?

Comment: If this was known to be possible, wouldn't you think they'd have it fixed as quickly as possible?

Comment: Can I know why someone downvotes my question

Comment: Not really, as the votes are designed to be anonymous and given without explanation. A downvote tells your question may lack research effort or be unuseful. It's highly probable the votes weren't *hacked*, though.

Comment: You've asked several questions at once that are jumbled up in a lot of assumptions. I've tried to focus the question a bit more, but it is still weak. "Is it possible to hack an account?" Uh, yes. "Can an account be hacked without the account owner knowing?" Again, yes - how would someone know?. "What other information is exposed in a StackOverflow account?" Whatever the account owner entered into the account. But all this seems obvious. What assumptions are you working with to ask these questions? Are you thinking that StackOverflow has special protections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people (and media) talk about an account being *hacked*, what actually happens in most cases is that a **password is either *weak*, *leaked*, *phished* or *reused***. This doesn't require a technical vulnerability in the system, so it could happen anywhere passwords are used, including Stack Exchange sites. This can be tackled with strong (recommendably random) passwords, good password hygiene and multi-factor authentication.

Comment: Well said @Esa, what I am thinking is  a stackOverfFower can do those things via posting something in StackOverflow

Comment: @coder_v_3.0 do *what* things?